# include & file() in PHP

Tags: php, file, include

my indexx.php goes

```
set_include_path('Dir_name');
```

and

```
include ('File_name.php');
```

In File_name.php
i ask

```
file(file2.txt)
```

and I error

> Warning: file(file2.txt): failed to open stream: No such file or
>   directory in \..\dir_name\File_name.php on line 7

it is like PHP searching for `file2.txt` inside of `File_name.php`

can anyone explain why? and how to overcome?

generally I have a dir contenning a php with functions that is opening a file in its open directory. I mean `file2.txt` & file_name are in the same dir `dir_name`.

P.S for those wounderning I'm a noob, so any help will be appricated :-)
by the way if i include the `file2.txt` it will work...

Comment: Please explain properly what exactly your problem is.

Comment: Kolink solved my problem
I have a folder coteining the a file.php with functions in it, one of them is file(file2.txt) that is a file in the same folder.

if open file.php dirctly, it will file(file2.txt), but when I inlude the file.php from the parent folder by:
index.php {

set_include_path('dir_name');
include ('file.php');
}
then I will have an error with the file(file.txt).

anyway thank - Kolink solved my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`file`](http://php.net/file) will not use the include path unless you tell it to by passing the `FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH` constant as the second parameter.

Comment: I add the FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH to file(file.txt,FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH) 

and it is working. THANKS.